# nohup doesn't work with chromium

Tags: linux, bash, chromium, nohup

I am making a small shell script that launches various programs after the boot. I use `dialog` for making a menu and then a simple case statement that runs desired applications. 
Everything works perfectly except my favourite browser Chromium.

`nohup chromium &` doesn't work - when I close the terminal Chromium closes too.

Here is my script:

```
selection=`dialog --menu "Choose a session:" 20 50 10 "Surfing" "" "Surfing (blank)" "" "Programming" "" "Gaming" "" "Nothing" "" --stdout`

case "$selection" in
    "Surfing" )
        nohup chromium http://www.facebook.com &
        nohup chromium http://www.twitter.com &
        nohup chromium http://reader.google.com &
        nohup chromium http://plus.google.com &
        nohup chromium http://www.youtube.com &
        nohup chromium http://www.reddit.com &
        nohup chromium http://mail.google.com &

        nohup sonata &
        mpc play &
        ;;
    "Surfing (blank)" )
        nohup chromium &>/dev/null </dev/null &
        nohup sonata &

        mpc play &
        ;;
    "Programming" )
        nohup subl &
        nohup chromium ~/Programming &
        nohup sonata &

        mpc play &
        ;;
    "Gaming" )
        nohup thunar ~/HRY &
        ;;
    * )
        echo "nothing" ;;
esac
read && exit
```

And part of my `.xinitrc`:

```
urxvt -e sh ~/session.sh &
```

Answer (score 5):

`nohup chromium-browser & disown` should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Should I rephrase? Adding `disown` after ampersand in commands provided in the question actually will resolve issue - chromium wouldn't close after closing terminal. Please explain - what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. I find `disown` is the perfect solution to this problem, since I generally don't want GUI applications that I open regularly from terminal windows to be considered as shell jobs to begin with, which also has the side effect of avoiding `HUP` signals when the terminal is closed.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Alexander. [I am still not sure why nohup alone doesn't work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162749/why-is-chromium-browser-killed-when-i-close-the-terminal-despite-nohup)

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this information is usefull:
when i use 'nohup chromium-browser &' and closed the terminal with ALT+F4 chromium closes too, but when close it whit CTRL+D, exit or with the X in the top of the window  chromium continues runing. Any ideas of why that happens? it only happens with chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of read && exit, just exit, it works fine here.